# How to scroll to anchor link in webview from android button?

Tags: android

I have a WebView in my Android App that is loading an HTML string using the loadDataWithBaseURL() method.

```
 w = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
 w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 String html = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Smooth Scroll</title> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- stylesheets --> <style type="text/css"> body { max-width: 40em; width: 88%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; } </style> </head> <body> <main id="top"> <nav> <hr> </nav> <section> <p> <strong>Ease-Out</strong><br> <a data-scroll href="#ANCHORLINK">Quad</a><br> </p> <p> .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br> .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br> .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>. </p> <p id="ANCHORLINK"><a data-scroll href="#1@#%^-bottom">SCROLL TO ANCHOR LINK!</a></p> <p> .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br> .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br> .<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>. </p> </html>"
 w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar",html,"text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

I want to use a android button to scroll to anchor link in webview. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your `String html` is broken.  Because you've nested double quotes without the escape slashes.

Also, you need to make sure that you didn't nest your `WebView` inside a `ScrollView` in your layout.  Because `WebView` has its own scroll function, and it might not work properly, if you nest it inside a `ScrollView`.

You can do it with an android Button as follows:

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`

```
   w = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
   w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   String html = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=\"en\"> <head>....<body><p id=\"top\">Top of the page content</p>....</body></html>";
   w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar",html,"text/html", "utf-8", "");

   Button topButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topButton);
   topButton.setOnClickListener(TopButtonHandler);
```

Then outside the `onCreate` function:

```
View.OnClickListener TopButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        w.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"top\").scrollIntoView()");
    }
};`
```

I got this to work with an html file in my assets folder.  Which is a little different from loading a string html.  But a string html should work the same way, as long as it doesn't have any errors, such as forgetting to put escape slashes for nested double quotes.

Instead of using an android `Button`, you can also get an html link to work this way inside your html file, located in your assets folder:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
   ....
   </head>
   <body>
   <p id="top">Content at the top of the page</p>

    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

   <a href="#top">Go to Top</a>

  </body>
  </html>
```

When you click on the `Go To Top` link, then the page will scroll to the top paragraph, provided that you didn't nest your `WebView` inside a `ScrollView` in your layout.

Comment: Thanks!         webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(...).scrollIntoView()"); worked for me, after trying other multiple ways